# How to combine different react components?

Tags: reactjs

I have made a project for mobile UI and one for desktop UI for website. How can I combine both by using something like 
**react-responsive** is there any way to do this.

Comment: it's unclear what you are trying to do and what you currently have. What do you mean by mobile UI? Is a app or website? You need to edit your question. In case if you mean you build a mobile app with react-native, then this is something you might be interesting https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/

Comment: @Yunhai It is a website with different UI for mobile and desktop